# Devise extensions (module) order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, bundler, gemfile

I have written a devise extension, that has a hook `Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user, auth, options|` and updates resource on authentication.

I am using a two factor authentication gem which uses `Warden::Manager.after_authentication` hook as well. My problem is that I need my extension to execute it first.

I have tried reordering gems in Gemfile, reordering extensions in `devise :ext1, :ext2..` and uploading my gem which I had locally to rubygems.

Answer (score 0):

`Warden::Manager.after_authentication` can take (as a parameter) a name of a method, that is used for adding new hook to the hooks array. By default it is `:push`. 
https://github.com/hassox/warden/blob/fa24dcbf34022d85dce8db51dd11bbbe5a6fddcc/lib/warden/hooks.rb#L76

You need to pass `:unshift` for your hook to be inserted to the beginning.

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication({}, :unshift) do |user, auth, options|
  # ...
end
```